# Grails list view not working

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I am trying out tutorials from [this youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/user/mdk0705/videos) by Mike Kelly.

I completed all installations successfully. Now trying out [dynamic scaffolding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hVXw2DoI_8), but its list is not working.

This is how the `show` page looks like when I added a new `EndUser`:

[image]

Now when I try to see list of `EndUser`s, (see the pointing link at bottom-left corner of above image), the link actually points to `index` page. And when I click on it, it opens up index page with **NO** rows listed in table (see below image).

[image]

I also tried to access list by using url: `http://localhost:9000/ProjectTracker/endUser/list`, but then it resulted into 404 error:

[image]

When I saw the database console, i found the data got inserted in it:

[image]

(**All files (controllers, domain files, etc.) are same as mentioned in the video tutorials**)

Comment: Which version of grails are you using? Is the same as the one in the tutorial?

Comment: I am using latest ggts (windows ggts based on eclipse 4.4.2) from http://spring.io/tools/ggts/all , it has grails-2.4.4

Comment: Grails 2.4.4 uses the "index" instead of the "list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for grails version 2.4.4 :

As suggested by @DavidChavez we can write those `index` and `list` methods as given. Or simply relying on dynamic scaffolding, we can just **ignore** writing / **remove** `index` and `list` methods. The dynamic scaffolding will take care of calling `index` by default, which internally calls `list` method.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved my life. I was using dynamic scaffolding only. But the controller had a index method generated by default. After reading your comment I removed the index method and voila, I was able to see the list.

Answer (score 1):

Since grails 2.3.x the list.gsp has been replaced with index.gsp
Now you have to find why the records are not been saved in the database.

The way the scaffold generates the index and list methods in 2.4.4 should be something like this:

```
def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
}

def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [endUserInstanceList: EndUser.list(params), endUserInstanceTotal: EndUser.count()]
}
```

Try with those ones.

Comment: Oh, Ok. . (i forgot to mention in question)Actually i looked at database and i see the data is inserted in db and is available there. But its not getting listed on page.

Comment: In the tutorial he is using the index with no info about the list of objects. 
Try using the generate-controller script instead of using those methods.
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Command%20Line/generate-controller.html
The tutorial you are using is obsolete, I recommend reading the official documentation or trying to find a book of the version of grails you are using

Comment: ya.. that solved the problem! using static scaffolding works. but then it's cumbersome task. Now, I have to see dynamic scaffolding in new version. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

try this in EndUserController, for grails 2.4.4

```
def index() {
    [endUserInstanceList: EndUser.list(params), endUserInstanceTotal: EndUser.count()]
}
```